# Problem with plate intel integrated video and html5, the videos look with yellow dots rain

Tags: 12.04, drivers, video, intel, html5

I tell them that I have a laptop hp 550 with ubuntu 12.04 I have the following problem.

I see youtube videos of popcorn and a shower of yellow dots. I guess the problem must be between my motherboard intel integrated video (Intel Corporation Mobile GME965/GLE960 ) and html5 format. I say this because I've been looking for quite some time in various forums , and many raise the issue that may be the flash. In my case it is not because probe all possible solutions and none turned out , but I have also this problem in both chrome and chromium using html5 and not flash using firefox . In the system of popcorn torrent video for me happens the same , I guess I will use html5 .

On the other hand I'm pretty sure it's incompatible my video card because I have another machine (desktop ) with the same OS and nvidia board , and I walk all perfect.

screenshot. http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140501060650687879.png

This happens to me in both small screen and full

Any suggestions to solve this?

From already thank you very much

PD : Sorry but is well understood, I'm using the google translator

Comment: the video that you are possibly watching based on the address bar in your image has been pulled. Can you post another example which is still accessible? I'd like to confirm that the problem is actually on your end and not just a bad video uploaded to youtube.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

It happens in all the videos, here I leave youtube 3 captures.

http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140502033027191674.png

http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140502033258377696.png

http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140502033345570057.png

Comment: I had the same problem checking the first one of your next 3 captures at less than an hour old, didn't bother with the rest. Taking this at face value my best guess is below.

Comment: wants to give me a youtube link of you to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove adobe flash:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-restricted-extras adobe-flashplugin flashplugin-installer
```

(Note: some of these packages may not be installed in your system, adjust accordingly)

Reinstall adobe flash:

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Type "flash" without quotes into the search box and hit enter.
3. Click on Adobe Flash Plugin in the search results.
4. Click the Install button.

The flash plugin will work with Firefox, Chromium, SeaMonkey, Iceweasel, Iceape, Galeon, Epiphany and Konqueror (among others).

If that doesn't work try this:

Open a video in Firefox from YouTube. Right click the video and there should be a popup. Notice that it mentions a HTML5 trial. This is the culprit. Down in the corner of this, there is a section that says something like 'remove me from the HTML5 trial'. Click this. It will then revert back to the original flash settings and the videos will run very well, just like they used to.

If instead your problem is with HTML5 (in chromium and or popcorn) as I finally understand to be the problem in this case - go to this link:

http://www.youtube.com/html5 in the offending browser (chromium for instance)

And click use the default player.